# CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT Parameter meaning

Tags: scrapy

I would like to know CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT=1 
    Is it forced to quit like kill -s 9 pid if an error occurs, or after all the follow-up work is completed after encountering an error, then exit like kill 2 pid Because I am a distributed crawler, I will record all the information of each request. I want it to report an error and then stop running. After modifying the error, I can continue to crawl at the last stop.
In addition, I configured to retry 5 times if a request is unreasonable. If I add CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT, it will affect the configuration above.

Answer (score 2):

[`CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html?highlight=CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT#std:setting-CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT), if reached, will call the `crawler.engine.close_spider` function, which will shutdown the spider in an orderly fashion. It will not be killed.

For as long as your RetryMiddleware keeps retrying the requests, they are not counted as errors.

You can not continue to crawl at the last stop. For that you will need [job control](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html).